# How do I make sure that my plugin only runs on article detail pages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

Basically, I want my jQuery plugin to run only on article pages, that is, not on the home page, or other pages. Right now, I am doing this in the following way:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    launchPlugin();
}
```

In other words, if the `is_single()` function returns true, I start my plugin. Am I doing it right? Is it universally acceptable for all WordPress blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be correct. [Is_single](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) returns true on single post pages, both normal and custom post types. Note that if you also want to run your script on pages, you will need [`is_singular`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/). The latter allows you to specify which post types the script should be included with, so it gives you more flexibility.

And yes, this should work for all WordPress blogs, though you should always wonder what happens if some other plugin interferes with yours. There's no 100% guarantee that it will always work.

Comment: When you use `is_singular` it is not only true for posts and pages. It is true for `is_attachment()` also.

Comment: @Ranuka. That is correct. Depending on whether OP wants to run his script on attachment posts as well, he can specify it in the parameters of `is_singular`.